# Join multiple columns on MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying to join multiple columns on a MySQL table.  I can't figure out how I can retrieve multiple columns into one single row, so I can display one row on my page.

**table: employee_timesheet**

```
id    employee_id    service_area_name    sign_off_1    sign_off_2  sign_off_3    created_date           status       last_updated
1     2              London               Rom           Director    NULL          2015-02-11 17:22:44    Submitted    2015-02-11 17:22:44
```

**table (empty): employees_timesheet_sign_off_team_leaders**

```
id    employee_id    timesheet_id    sign_off_key    team_leader_id
```

**table: employees_timesheet_sign_off_roms**

```
id    employee_id    timesheet_id    rom_id    sign_off_key
1     2              1               4         sign_off_1
2     2              1               5         sign_off_1
```

**table: team_leaders**

```
id    first_name    last_name    email                  reports_to    status    date_added              last_updated
2     Bob           Test         me@mydomain.com        4             Active    2015-02-03 12:50:25     2015-02-03 13:28:56
```

**table: roms**

```
id    first_name    last_name    email                          status    date_added              last_updated
4     Bill          Gates        bill@mydomain123445678.com     Active    2015-02-03 13:14:07     2015-02-03 13:28:40
5     Ben           Morris       ben@mydomain123445678.co.uk    Active    2015-02-11 17:35:43     NULL
```

I need to join the above tables to get the following result:

```
ID: 1
Team Leader: (null)
Rom: Bill Gates,Ben Morris
Date: 2015-02-11 17:22:44
```

It would be very much appreciated if someone could help with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I tried this: http://pastebin.com/umDunz22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your use case, you need to use the GROUP_CONCAT function: http://www.percona.com/blog/2013/10/22/the-power-of-mysqls-group_concat/. The query would look something like:

```
SELECT et.id, CONCAT(l.first_name, ' ', l.last_name) 'team_leader', GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(r.first_name, ' ', r.last_name)), et.last_updated
FROM employee_timesheet et
INNER JOIN employees_timesheet_sign_off_roms etr ON et.id = etr.timesheet_id
INNER JOIN roms r ON etr.rom_id = r.id
LEFT JOIN employees_timesheet_sign_off_team_leaders etl ON et.id = etl.timesheet_id
LEFT JOIN team_leaders l ON etl.team_leader_id = l.id
GROUP BY et.id, team_leader, et.last_updated
```